# Why would this javascript not work in IE7 or Safari?

Tags: javascript

Firefox handles it fine, but Safari and IE7 silently fail and do not insert the element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ul = document.getElementById('xg_navigation').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  ul.innerHTML = '<li id="xg_tab_home" class="xg_subtab"><a href="http://somedomain.com/">Some Text</a></li>' + ul.innerHTML;
</script>
```

This is with an exisitng html structure like:

```
<div id="xg_navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="...">Foo</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I dont have control over the HTML, but I do have the ability to insert a snippet of javascript in the page body.

Sadly I appear to be poorly educated on cross browser javascript support.  Do I need to hook it it up via an onPageLoad sort of event somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are manipulating the DOM before it has been loaded, try adding that snippet of code inside the `window.onload` listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('xg_navigation').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    ul.innerHTML = '<li id="xg_tab_home" class="xg_subtab"><a   href="http://somedomain.com/">Some Text</a></li>' + ul.innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IE cannot access DOM elements until the document load is complete.

Comment: Then what is the proper way to set a fucntion to be run when the page is done loading that works cross browser?

Comment: As suggested by Luca, you use the window.onload event to catch when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to wait for the DOM to be ready to execute a script that modifies the DOM.

An easy way to do that is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(function() { 
    $('#xg_navigation ul').prepend('<li id="xg_tab_home" class="xg_subtab"><a href="http://somedomain.com/">Some Text</a></li>');
});
```